# AngularJS Directive data binding not happening from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am facing the problem of data binding from controller to directive because of delay in response from the server.

To better understand just see a small program below.When I remove the timeout function, binding happens.

```
<msg track="{{customer}}"></msg>



angular.module('myApp').directive('msg',  function() {

  return {
      scope: {
        track :"@"
      },
      link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

      },
      template : "<a href>{{track}}</a>"
  }

});

angular.module('myApp').controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $scope.customer = "shreyansh";
    }, 5000);
    // assume some service call inside controller 
    // service1.getData().then(function(data){$scope.customer = data})
}]);
```

How can i fix above problem so that above code should render as

```
<msg track="shreyansh" class="ng-isolate-scope"><a href="" class="ng-binding">shreyansh</a></msg>.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: use $timeout of angular native

Comment: Or use $scope.$apply(); //this triggers a $digest  after value assignment in setTimeout

Comment: can you please share your code

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('myService', function($http) {
  var promise;
  var myService = {
    getData: function() {
      if (!promise) {
        promise = $http.get('test.json').then(function(response) {
          return response.data;
        });
      }
      return promise;
    }
  };
  return myService;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function(myService, $scope) {
  myService.getData().then(function(d) {
    $scope.data = d;
  });
});

app.directive('msg', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      track: "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    },
    template: "<a href>{{track}}</a>"
  }
});



 <msg track="{{data.name}}"></msg>
```

test.json file

```
{
  "name": "Pete"
}
```

Comment: Hi Sumit , thanks for your answer, but I cannot use both $timeout and $scope.$apply(). Because setTimeout I just used to show you delay in getting the data from the server and also $scope.$apply() is not good for execution speed . It will check for each and every scope variable .

Comment: Do you have any other solution in which when ever there is change in customer value automatically it should reflect in DOM (directive)

Comment: use $scope.$digest() to update scope at controller level

Comment: I am looking for some better solution in  which i don't have to invoke $digest cycle manually

Comment: Actually you should use angular native services. $timeout() takes care of the current scope and runs in the same digest cycle. No need to use $apply() and $digest() in that case

Comment: dude there is no such timeout function anywhere in code , I just used it to show you that there is delay in response from the server while calling restful API, and after that only i can bind the data .

Comment: Can you please provide exact scenario?

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comments. Try out. Specify restrict: 'E' in directive.